# How can retrieve a text file send from iphone appliction to asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, json

I need to retrieve a text file send from iphone application to my asp.net application .

```
 HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    NameValueCollection nvc = context.Request.Form;
    string file = nvc["text_file"];
```

Is it possible ?? please help.I have used this code for retrieving single variables.,It works properly..but in the case of text files is it possible ???

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how this iPhone application is sending the file. Whether it is using the `multipart/form-data` content type which would allow you to retrieve it by name from the `context.Request.Files["text_file"]` property (NOT `context.Request.Form`) or whether it just wrote the file contents directly into the request payload in which case you could read it from the `context.Request.InputStream`.